# SP 2013 - Disable Upload in Enhanced RichTextField

Tags: 2013, file-upload, rich-text, image-upload

We are using an enhanced RichTextField as Description Field where
Users are able to paste Images into their Description.

Unfortunately, SharePoint by design also offers an upload function within the enhanced RichTextField to a selected document library.

This is not wanted. (
I honestly don't really understand why someone would upload documents to a textfield and not to the item itself)

**Does anyone have a solution to disable the upload functionality on the richtexteditor ?**

My only possible thought is disabling the control via JavaScript onClick event which doesn't seem really good to me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide Upload button with RichTextEditor, unless you use `HideCUstomAction` for hiding Upload button and then attach it to specific Document Library/ContentType etc.

See example: http://www.ktskumar.com/blog/2010/10/hide-button-from-sharepoint-ribbon/

Comment: Firstly, thx for your response. The Upload Button doesn't belong to the List, it belongs to the control or am I wrong here? Also im looking for a programmatical solution.