# Sharepoint 2013 - hide ribbon controls

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I have a SP list that contains six Multiple line of text(Enhanced rich text) fields.

For 3 of the controls, I need to hide only the Upload File icon from the ribbon.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

**Add this below code to Script Editor Webpart**

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById('Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions').style.display= 'none';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question here:

[SP 2013 - Disable Upload in Enhanced RichTextField](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84863/sp-2013-disable-upload-in-enhanced-richtextfield)

Not sure if there are other ways, but one way is to hide it through CSS,

```
#Ribbon\.EditingTools\.CPInsert\.Links\.UploadFile-Large
{   
    display:none !important;
}
```

Now, as for showing it and hiding it depending on the context, you can do that using a JavaScript event handler, maybe using the css match above.

e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660633/detect-click-inside-outside-of-element-with-single-event-handler

rough example:

```
if(mydiv).click{
 $("#Ribbon\.EditingTools\.CPInsert\.Links\.UploadFile-Large").hide();
}
if(myotherdiv).click{
 $("#Ribbon\.EditingTools\.CPInsert\.Links\.UploadFile-Large").show();
}
```